# Android Support Library Specification

Tags: android, android-support-library

Recently I've noticed an error in my gradle files for both mobile and wear, that says the following.

[image: Error Message]

I've tried changing to the different versions but it is still showing an error no matter what version I change it to. Can someone give me some guidance on solving this please. My gradle is as follows,

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

}

The error is actually at compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0'. I'm assuming that is because this is the first one on the list it come across.

Comment: maybe one of these libraries depends on the old `23.0.1` version and is causing a dependency conflict

Comment: I suppose I'll just have to go through the libraries and see if that is the case. Could be right, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.0'

these are conflicting with each other you have to select one from these two.

The issue is with these together "com.google.android.support"  and 
"com.android.support"

will be fixed in the upcoming release from google.